# global COLOR opacity hover overlay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using the below for a global link opacity overlay.

```
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;  opacity: 0.6; /* css standard */
    filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* internet explorer */
} /* mouse over link */
```

**How can I add color to this?** Is this possible with CSS or am I looking at a JS / jQuery solution only?

Comment: Would it not be as simple as: `color: red;`?

Comment: Really? I've just tried plugging that in and I see the same basic opacity hover?

Comment: Bleh- take it back, I see it as my level of opacity is adjusted. Not as harsh as I hoped tho

Comment: It is so faint, it's hardly there though. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the colour e.g. black to be on the background then your code will be

```
a:hover {text-decoration: none;  opacity: 0.6; /* css standard */
filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* internet explorer */ /* mouse over link */ background: #000; }
```

and if you want the a tag to have a colour of eg black then your css will look like this

```
a:hover {text-decoration: none;  opacity: 0.6; /* css standard */
filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* internet explorer */  /* mouse over link */ color: #000; }
```

for some reason you have an extra `}` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
a:hover{
    /* your stuff here */
    color:#f00;                // older browsers
    color: rgba(255,0,0,0.4);  // browsers with rgba support (r,g,b,alphaOpacity)
}
```

Comment: This works to the point I see it's reading, but it's so faint, no matter how much I toggle the opacity.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you dont need opacity at all. The effect you are searching for is a tranparent background. Use `rgba()` with a `rgb()` fallback and define a transparent background instead.

```
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;  
    background: rgb(255,0,0) /* fallback */
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.6) /* red with 60% opactiy */
    color: #000;
}
```